# Retrieve value in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

I want to display the elements of the database from the nodes. I can display them in the console but I have error on ngFor and I do not understand.

Thank you I am very beginner
please help me

adresse page.ts

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    let useradresse = firebase.database().ref('adresse/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    useradresse.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((addressSnapshot) => {
        console.log (addressSnapshot.val()); // shows the address value 
        this.adresse = addressSnapshot.val();
      })
    })

  }
```

adresse.page.ts

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let adress of adresse; let i = index" (click)="onViewAdresse(i)">
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col size="9" >
                        <!--<ion-col size="9" (click)="goTo(adress)">-->
                    <div><b>{{adress.prenom}} {{adress.nom}} </b></div>
                    <div>{{adress.commune}}</div>
                    <div>{{adress.numeroF}}</div>

                </ion-col>
                <ion-col size="3">
                    <div class="color-edit"><b>Modifier</b></div>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
          </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7nWK.jpg)

[Base de donnée](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCYWF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Define property 
    private addresse = [];

And then in your snapshot.forEach() method convert Val() to array like this...

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var item = childSnapshot.val();
    item.key = childSnapshot.key;

    this.addresse.push(item);
});
```

Basically, you get object from snapshot, you need to convert it to array in order to loop through *ngFor.